# How to scale the y-axis in matplotlib, starting from zero

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot my image with a pixel indexing technique where only the white pixel is shown. The code can be seen below:

```
img = cv2.imread('img.png')
img = cv2.resize(img, (180, 119))
arr0 = np.array(img)

height, width, _ = arr0.shape

x = range(width)
y = [height - np.argwhere(arr0[:, i, 0]==255).mean() for i in x]

plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

the result is:   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bjnu.png

but I want to make the y-axis start from zero not from 63 like in the image shown.

I've tried with `np.tan(height)` but the result is not what I expected. Any ideas?

UPDATE!! I SIMPLY KNOW HOW TO SET THE Y-AXIS TO ZERO!

```
img = cv2.imread('img.png')
img = cv2.resize(img, (180, 119))
arr0 = np.array(img)

height, width, _ = arr0.shape

x = range(width)
y = [63.5 - np.argwhere(arr0[:, i, 0]==255).mean() for i in x] #Just change the height into the value from the start

plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

thanks all!!